# Android TextView Right Side

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to set imageview in left side and text view right side in LinearLayout. I am not able to set TextView as end of LinearLayout. How can I do it ?[image]

I want Your Name on end of LinearLayout in line of imageview.

My XML is like below.

```html
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/action_qod_save"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtusername"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Your Name"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:typeface="sans"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Full XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffeeeeee"
    >


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="24dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >


        <LinearLayout

            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgview"
                        android:layout_width="128dp"
                        android:layout_height="128dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        app:civ_border_color="#EEEEEE"
                        app:civ_border_width="4dp"
                        app:civ_shadow="true"
                        app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
                        app:civ_shadow_color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:id="@+id/txtquote"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:textSize="19dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:typeface="sans"
                    android:lines="5"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:text="Quote of The Day Text Will be Here">
                </TextView>

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/action_qod_save"
                        android:src="@drawable/new_share_btn"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtusername"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Your Name"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:typeface="sans"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView

                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
                android:shadowDx="-5"
                android:shadowDy="-5"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="Status Of The Day">

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try using this code in your textview   `android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
        android:drawableEnd="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"`

Tell me if it works...

Comment: give the code of whole layout may be you did something  wrong in parent layout.

Comment: full xml code added. Thanks

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
<RelativeLayout

            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/action_qod_save"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtusername"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Your Name"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

if you want only linear layout  then Do this

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/action_qod_save"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <View
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtusername"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Your Name"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

but it is not suggested as it will place an empty view in between

Answer (score 0):

change textview gravity to `right`

```
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtusername"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Your Name"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
```

Comment: also change its width to match_parent

Answer (score 0):

Use layout_weight,gravity,layout_gravity property in the control to get design as you mentioned.

Use the following XML :

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/action_qod_save"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtusername"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Your Name"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</LinearLayout>
```